# Change Ribbon button without restarting Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am making a plugin who changes depending on a text file.
Is it possible to change a Ribbon button name without restarting the software Revit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You typically construct your panels and buttons during ExternalApplication Startup.
If you store as properties/fields the buttons or other UI elements you need to change, it is possible to change those objects at runtime from your commands or other events.

Comment: You state it's possible, but how???  I can find the RibbonItem (button) via iterating through the ribbon panels, but when I try to change the button properties - specifically the AutomationName, Image and Tooltip, the API doesn't allow it.  What's your solution for this?